# PDF viewer with multiple groups of files in multiple windows

Tags: pdf, tabs, session, viewer

I have a problem viewing / searching of a multitude of pdf files, like absence of a viewer with multiple groups of files.

I usually use Foxit Reader, which is excellent one,
it can remember and reopen documents, previously opened in tabs.
I've asked them about a feature, like this, but still no answer.

But I do need some viewer or editor which can open files in multiple windows, each with own set of files in tabs, loaded on demand in groups/sessions.

It would be great to have a solution multiplatform, like Windows(portable)/Linux.